# Function for updating state variable in class component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have various state variables. I can change it with a separate function, like this:

```
handleMusic=(event) =>
{
this.setState({musicList:event.target.value});
}

handleName=(event) =>
{
this.setState({nameList:event.target.value});
}
```

What I want is a function that has a state variable name as parameter and values and assign the same state variable with the provided values.

Something like this:

```
updateStateArray=(name,val) =>
{
this.setState({name:val}) //but this will create another state variable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
updateStateArray = (name,val) => {
  this.setState({ [name] : val})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState({ name: value })` will simply update the state `name` in this code.

You want [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).
`this.setState({ [name]: value })`